# Oднородны ли деепричастный оборот и оборот с предлогом "несмотря на"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, предлоги, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот

Могут ли быть однородны деепричастный оборот и оборот с предлогом "несмотря на"?

**Однако вскоре, оставив свои занятия и несмотря на преклонные лета, он отправился в монастырь.**

Или же здесь нужны две запятые? Или одна, чтобы "и" не выпячивала (Однако вскоре...и...он отправился в монастырь)?

Однако вскоре, оставив свои занятия, и(,) несмотря на преклонные лета, он отправился в монастырь.

Comment: Наверное, лучше перестроить фразу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Однако вскоре, оставив свои занятия и несмотря на преклонные лета, он отправился в монастырь.**

1) **Интонационный анализ дает нам однозначный ответ:** структура **данного предложения такова,** что оборот, состоящий из двух распространенных обстоятельств, связанных союзом И, должен быть обособлен, иначе (без обособления) **это предложение** не читается.

2) **Теперь надо объяснить семантику, то есть почему эти обстоятельства с разной грамматикой являются однородными**. Надо определить их значение. Безусловно, общей темой является уступка, то есть действие вопреки обстоятельствам. Поэтому можно говорить о сближенном значениии, то есть деепричастный оборот в данном контексте также имеет значение уступки. Дело в том, что и занятия, и преклонный возраст **одинаково мешали действию** нашего героя.

Answer (score 1):

Перечитал Розенталя [§94. Обособленные обстоятельства](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm). Не нашел соответствующей "буквы", но по духу пришел к выводу, что у нас есть два оборота - два однородных обстоятельства, соединенных союзом "и"; их не надо разделять запятой, но эта парочка должна обособляться, поскольку каждый оборот в отдельности требовал бы обособления. Так что знаки расставлены, на мой взгляд, верно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А может, они всё-таки неоднородны, сейчас подумалось. Одно обстоятельство - времени (оставив свои занятия), другое - уступки (несмотря на преклонные лета). Однородные отвечают на один вопрос. Т.е. однородности нет ни по смыслу, т.к. вопросы разные, ни формально, т.к. обстоятельства выражены разными конструкциями.

Comment: Не думаю, что *оставив свои занятия* - обстоятельство времени. Вполне можно считать, что оба отвечают на вопрос *как?*

Comment: Если обстоятельства неоднородны, то неверно ставить союз И: "в девятом часу и ложась в кровать" (?!)

Comment: Здесь деепричастный оборот не тянет на обстоятельство чего-либо. Он просто указывает на действие, предшествовавшее действию сказуемого (=оставил прежние занятия, затем двинулся в путь, чтобы заняться другим делом). Поэтому "и" здесь объединяет "бузину и дядьку" - с убирания союза и надо начинать правку, а потом уже с запятыми решать.